# Why am I receiving a m2m_field / __str__ error in Django?

Tags: django, unicode, django-models

Is the query below valid, given that the model is a ManyToManyField?  I am receiving the error I pasted below and wondering if it is because my query is wrong or if it is related to the unicode?  Should I switch Unicode to String?

```
Entry.objects.filter(author__user=username)[:4]
```

models.py

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.user, self.firstname, self.lastname)

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ManyToManyField(MyProfile, related_name='entryauthors')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text, self.author)
```

error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 572, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/root/proj/accounts/models.py", line 63, in __str__
    return u'%s %s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text, self.author)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 476, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 757, in __init__
    self.source_field_name = rel.field.m2m_field_name()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 15, in _curried
    return _curried_func(*(args + moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: As an aside - you have `__str__` for one model and `__unicode__` in another. The docs suggest you define `__str__` for all your models, and use the [`@python_2_unicode_compatible`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) decorator if you are using Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `self.author` in the `__str__` method. It is a `ManyRelatedManager`, not a list of the authors as you might expect. To fetch the related managers, you can do `self.author.all()`

```
def __str__(self):
    return u'%s %s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text, self.author.all())
```

However, including the authors in the `__str__` method means that you will do extra database queries whenever the `__str__` method runs. I recommend you remove it.

```
def __str__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text)
```

As an aside, I recommend you rename the field from `author` to `authors`, since each entry can have more that one author.

Comment: Thank you, this also brings up another issue which is that, each Entry should only have one author, so I'm guessing I should not be using a ManyToManyfield?

Comment: If each entry has a single author, then use a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).